# Facebook / Google oauth flow for iPhone app with server back-end

Tags: iphone, facebook, oauth

I'm developing an iPhone app that will have a server side (django). The user will be able to connect to their Facebook and Google accounts using Oauth 2. The calls to the Facebook and Google APIs will be from the server side, so I need a server-side token.

I'm not sure I got it all right for the flows though.

**Google**: This seems clear to me - I'll just follow the scheme for web server applications:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2 The app will open an embedded browser with the oauth login screen and once the user log in and authorize my app, Google will answer with the redirect to the link that I've provided and registered (which will be my server). The rest will be done on the server (exchanging the code for a token).

**Facebook**: I initially thought about the same flow, but according to point 5 in this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/checklist/
one should only use the SDK now so all the flow will happen on the iPhone side and then I'll need to send the token to the server. According to this post, it's possible:
[Can I use Facebook auth server side flow on an iPhone app and still have client side interactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606073/can-i-use-facebook-auth-server-side-flow-on-an-iphone-app-and-still-have-client)

Am I right with those 2 flows ?

Comment: Did you follow up on this? How did you solve the problem for facebook specifically?

Comment: For know, I only have the Google part implemented. It works, but I have a problem with the refresh token - I get the impression that it works OK, but only while the access token is still alive. Once it expires, well the refresh token returns me and invalid access token. As for now, I don't need more so didn't spend much time to find out what's going on. Will let you know once I do (and implement the Facebook part too)